# Case member to a single case

Tags: civicase

How can I add more members to a specific case?

Use case: We have group of people working on a case however these groups won't have same members everytime. How can add group of people specific to a case?

Adding members to Case resource results in adding to Case Resource group which is added to all cases. We don't want to go towards adding relationships. Any other ways we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviCRM 5.69 allows you to add a Custom field against Case as a multi-select contact reference field.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: wow, didn't know we could do a multi-select contact reference field via a custom field. Also loved the option for creating a custom field with Entity super beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

You can add people in the Roles section on manage case. Click the Add New Role button or click on the pencil icon on one of the rows to edit an existing one. You can have multiple of the same type.

[image]